# problems with display image from the database

Tags: php, database

I have image store in the the database but Iam not able to display them 
[the image in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/076z2.png) 
  i want to diplay the image here

```
<div class='panel-body $body_class' style='height:190px; word-wrap: break-word; overflow: auto;'>
  <img src='data:ads;base64' '>
  <p class='adtext'>$row_ad->text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then come back and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it.

```
<div class='panel-body $body_class' style='height:190px; word-wrap: break-word; overflow: auto;'>
  <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo $row_ad->image;?>' />
  <p class='adtext'><?php $row_ad->text ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanx man its works